# After Effects Element 3D rotation bug

Tags: adobe, effects, after-effects

I don't know how to explain this but the objects I make in ELEMENT 3D aren't 3D but more like 2.5D.

I made a video so you can see the problem.

https://sendvid.com/s1hv1ay3

My recording software didn't record the Element interface at 0:24, but I was trying to show in that interface that you could rotate it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

You're not understanding how Element3D (and aspects of the AE interface) work. Think of the layer you apply it to as being its own window "into a 3D world". You don't rotate the layer itself, you rotate the objects within the Element3D world by changing the parameters in the timeline or Effects controls pane. You were using the rotate tool in the video with the Element3D-effected layer selected. Don't do that. Use the individual parameters within Element. Another way to rotate around the 3D object(s) is to use the camera. I suspect this is what you were attempting after seeing a tutorial or something. What you do is make a two-node camera and use the camera tool by cycling through the tool with the "c" key until you get camera rotate, which looks a bit similar to the rotate layer tool. With a two-node camera, rotating the camera allows you to rotate around the point of interest of the camera so it rotates around the object in 3D space. I suggest you get a more familiar with how 3D works in AE (which is not "true 3D", not 2.5D, but is "Planar 3D"; the Element3D plugin is one of the best 3D-integrated plugins working within this model).

Answer (score 0):

don't ever move the layer the element 3d model is on.
Use the element effects controls (f3). usually found in group 1